# Qtableview resize

Tags: qt, qtableview, qdockwidget

I have several qdockwidget and within these a qtableview, as seen in the attached [picture](http://www.qtcentre.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=8228&d=1348059875), my problem is I want the tables are the same size of the dock.

I tried to do this and it does not work:

```
table-> resize (dock-> size());
```

Comment: Can't see the picture, it's behind a forum login. Please upload to a public image host, e.g. imgur.com.

Comment: http://cimginqt.blogspot.com/2012/09/picture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the cells in a table do not expand to fill the available
>   space. You can make the cells fill the available space by stretching
>   the last header section. Access the relevant header using
>   horizontalHeader() or verticalHeader() and set the header's
>   stretchLastSection property.
>   *Source:* [*QTableView Documentation*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html)

I hope that helps you. Cheers.